# Hidden Parent and Subdirectories with Powershell

Tags: powershell

Here's my issue. I'm trying to figure out how to hide a parent director and all the subdirectories I created with powershell. Here's the code that I'm using...
$f=ni -ItemType Directory -Path 'C:[name][name][name]\' -Force
$f.attributes = 'Hidden'
 My problem is that it will only hide that very last folder and not the entire path. Please help I'm out of hair and teeth.

$f=ni -ItemType Directory -Path 'C:[name][name][name]\' -Force
$f.attributes = 'Hidden'

$f=ni -ItemType Directory -Path 'C:[name][name][name]\' -Force
$f.attributes = 'Hidden'

Expected result is to have the parent and subdirectories hidden. What actually happens is only the last subdirectory is hidden.

Comment: [1] when posting code PLEASE do not use aliases. they are hard to read and **_may not exist on other systems_**. ///// [2] please read the instructions on how to post formatted code. it's markdown, so you likely already know it. [*grin*] ///// [3] why do you expect that setting any attribute on a lower level directory would change the higher level directory? [*frown*]

Comment: So this is starting to frustrate me...
$f=ni -ItemType Directory -Path 'C:\[name]\[name]\[name]\' -Force 
$f.attributes = 'Hidden' 
I'm not sure why it was all crammed into one line and the "\'s" were all deleted... But there's my script so far.

Comment: The last part of Lees comment is what you need to read. You are setting a variable to the full path, the last Directory in that path. If you want to change the attribute at the top...you need to get the top and set it there. So, create your structure then grab the parent directory and set the hidden attribute.

Comment: Thanks Lee_Dailey and M0lochwalker... Let me see if that works.

Comment: Think about what $f is. Go from there.

Comment: @D0cStr8nge - you are welcome! please do as m0lochwalker recommended and **_think about what you are telling the code to do_**. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the attribute on C:\Name instead.

Comment: This is the prudent way to do this, Just like default hidden shares on Windows, but it does not set the attribute on the subfolders (the OP primary request) as there is no recurse for this sort of thing as noted in my response (that whole bolded part). Yet, I still don't get why the OP wants to do this for the whole tree, rather than just setting ACLs.

Comment: It sounds like you agree my answer is adequate. OP can use -recurse if he needs.

Comment: The New-Item cmdlet does not have a -recurse switch. So, note the OP cannot use recurse for this effort as written.

Comment: I didn’t suggest they use -recurse on New-Item. I suggested they get their root Directory and work with that item.

Comment: I had forgotten that small piece of crucial information. That if I set the attribute on the parent all child folders receive the attribute as well.  I was trying to do something that can't be done. Once it was said I had to stop and say to myself... "Duh dummy can't do it that way."

Comment: @D0cStr8nge no problem, glad you seem to have it working!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why the wo lines?
They are doing exactly the same thing.

This is not a PowerShell specific issue. This is a Windows file system constraint. Thus, this same thing would happen if you did this at DOS (cmd.exe) or any other language and tried this.

Attributes are applied to the single thing you pass to it. A directory tree is not a single thing, it is a collection.

So, if you what to do this, the you are going to have to iterate of the tree.

***Lastly, if you hide the parent, I am not really sure why you'd need to hide the children as they would be hidden by default (even with the attribute not set)***, well, unless you knew the parent name and the navigate to the children. Yet, either way discovering hidden stuff is brain dead simple. So, I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish by this.

Anyway, here is what I mean...

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path 'E:\Parent\Child\GrandChild' -Force

# Results

<#
    Directory: E:\Parent\Child


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         7/7/2019   7:16 PM                GrandChild 

Notice that doing what you are doing, only returns the last thing, by Windows 
file system design. This is why you are only getting the setting on the one 
item.
#>



# Not all of them that were created - To get all things in a tree, you have to recurse.
Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\Parent' -Recurse

# Results

<#

    Directory: E:\Parent


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         7/7/2019   7:16 PM                Child


    Directory: E:\Parent\Child


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         7/7/2019   7:16 PM                GrandChild
#>


<#
Since there is no -recurse in New-Item, as per the help files info ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-6

... after doing the first line to create the tree, iterate to set the attribute 
on the children and grandchildren, etc., first,  then act on the parent.

Again, breaking down the object.
#>


($NewTree = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path 'E:\Parent\Child\GrandChild' -Force)

# Results

<#
    Directory: E:\Parent\Child


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         7/7/2019   7:16 PM                GrandChild 
#>

$NewTree.Name

# Results
# GrandChild


$NewTree.FullName

# Results
# E:\Parent\Child\GrandChild

$NewTree.Parent

# Results

<#
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         7/7/2019   8:10 PM                Child  
#>

$NewTree.PSChildName

# Results
# GrandChild


Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\Parent' -Recurse

# Results 

<#
 Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\Parent' -Recurse


    Directory: E:\Parent


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         7/7/2019   8:30 PM                Child


    Directory: E:\Parent\Child


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         7/7/2019   8:30 PM                GrandChild
#>

# So, iterate the children and set the attribute

($ChildFolders = (Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\Parent' -Recurse)) | 
ForEach{$PSItem.Attributes = 'Hidden'}

# Then set the final parent.
($ParentFolder = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'E:\' | 
Where Name -eq 'Parent').Attributes = 'Hidden'

Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\Parent' -Recurse

# Resutls

<#

#>


Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\Parent' -Force -Recurse

# Results

<#
 Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\Parent' -Force -Recurse


    Directory: E:\Parent


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d--h--         7/7/2019   8:39 PM                Child


    Directory: E:\Parent\Child


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d--h--         7/7/2019   8:39 PM                GrandChild
#>
```

Comment: first line created a variable and the second sets attributes... they don't do the same thing.